# Symfony2 query error (while the same works under Doctrine2)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I am using both Doctrine2 and Symfony2 but Symfony2 fails me at a task I am able to accomplish in Doctrine2 (the 'standalone' version).

In Doctrine2:

I have 2 classes, Outcome, Ticket as such:

```
namespace Entity;
/** @Entity @Table(name="tickets") */
class Ticket {
    /**  @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") */
    private $id;
    /** @Column(type="string", length=100) */
    private $title;
    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="Outcome", mappedBy="ticket") */
    private $outcomes;
    /* with setters and getters for title and outcomes */
    public function __toString() {
        return  $this->getTitle().' ('.$this->getId().')';
    }
    public function __construct () {
        $this->outcomes=new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace Entity;
/** @Entity @Table(name="outcomes") */
class Outcome  {
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") */
    private $id;
    /** @Column(type="string", length=100) */
    private $text;
    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ticket", inversedBy="outcomes") @JoinColumn(nullable=false) */
    private $ticket;
    public function __toString() {
        return  $this->getText().' ' .' ('.$this->getId().')';
    }
}
```

in my index.php I use

```
$query = $em->createQuery ("SELECT t,o FROM Entity\Ticket t LEFT JOIN t.outcomes o WHERE t.id=1");
$query->useResultCache(true);
$tickets_2 = $query->execute();
$ticket_2 = $tickets_2[0];
$amount=count($ticket_2->getOutcomes());
echo $ticket_2." --ticket\n";
echo $amount." --outcomes\n";
```

and I get the correct output

now in Symfony2 I use the following definitions for the entities:

```
namespace test\DemoBundle\Entity;
/** @orm:Entity @orm:Table(name="tickets") */
class Ticket {
    /**  @orm:Id @orm:Column(type="integer") 
         @orm:GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") */
    private $id;
    /** @orm:Column(type="string", length=100) */
    private $title;
    /** @orm:OneToMany(targetEntity="Outcome", mappedBy="response") */
    private $outcomes;
    ...
}
```

```php
namespace test\DemoBundle\Entity;
/** @orm:Entity @orm:Table(name="outcomes") */
class Outcome  {
    /** @orm:Id @orm:Column(type="integer") @orm:GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") */
    private $id;
    /** @orm:Column(type="string", length=100) */
    private $text;
    /** @orm:ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ticket", inversedBy="outcomes") @orm:JoinColumn(nullable=false) */
    private $ticket;
    ....
}
```

now, I've set up a controller with a test function:

```
namespace test\DemoBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use test\DemoBundle\Entity\Ticket as Ticket;
use test\DemoBundle\Entity\Outcome as Outcome;
class TicketController extends Controller { 
    ...
    public function testAction() {
        $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');  
        $query = $em->createQuery ("SELECT t, o
            FROM test\DemoBundle\Entity\Ticket t  
            LEFT JOIN  t.outcomes o
            WHERE t.id=1");
        $query->useResultCache(true);
        $tickets_2 = $query->execute();
        $ticket_2 = $tickets_2[0];
        $amount=count($ticket_2->getOutcomes());
        $prepared_result=$ticket_2." --ticket ".$amount." --outcomes ";
        $response = new Response($prepared_result);
        return $response; 
    }
}
```

at this point I get an error while trying to execute the last query like so:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE t0_.id = 1' at line 1

from the webdebugger I get the following syntax from PDO:

```sql
SELECT t0_.id AS id0,
 t0_.title AS title1,
 o1_.id AS id2,
 o1_.text AS text3,
 o1_.ticket_id AS ticket_id4
FROM tickets t0_ 
LEFT JOIN WHERE t0_.id = 1
```

so I guess I am missing something after the LEFT JOIN so that's why I am gettint the error in the first place?

What am I doing wrong?/What should I do?

Comment: ok found error/** @orm:OneToMany(targetEntity="Outcome", mappedBy="response") */ "response" should be "ticket"